# $select returning empty json result for Navigation Property

Tags: json, asp.net-web-api, odata, asp.net-web-api-odata

i am using v4 of oData in an web api.

my get all call returns the entire set (total 3 objects) properly.

```
http://localhost:9910/api/CommandsRest
```

[image]

but trying to select just the StoreCommand gives me 3 blank objects

```
http://localhost:9910/api/CommandsRest?$select=StoreCommand
```

trying to expand StoreCommand gives me StoreCommand but does not gives me its Navigation Properties

```
http://localhost:9910/api/CommandsRest?$expand=StoreCommand
```

i want just the StoreCommand property of the main Object with all its Navigation Properties.

Comment: Please post the source code for yout `Get` method.

Comment: Get is returning IQueryable of the entity in apicintroller using mongoDB's FindAll method in the repository. Also have the queryable attribute. You want me to update the code or this info is enough?

Comment: The `Queryable` attribute is obsolete. You should be using the `System.Web.OData.EnableQuery` attribute.

Comment: Soory it is enable query

Comment: I mean it is already EnableQuery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/CommandsRest?$select=StoreCommand&$expand=StoreCommand($expand=DictionaryVariables)`. This will get you each StoreCommand with the DictionaryVariables property expanded inline.

If you want *all* of the navigation properties of StoreCommand, you must list them explicitly in the nested expand clause. E.g., `$expand=DictionaryVariables,DictionaryNestedSplitVariables,DictionaryMultipleVariables,TabularVariables`.

Note that I tested these URIs using in memory data, not MongoDB.

Comment: Awsome it worked. So i have to do it for the entire graph? No way to get the complete graph simply?

Comment: Not using query options. If you want a compact way to return a large graph, define on OData function that performs the appropriate MongoDB query. See [Functions & Actions in Web API V2.2 for OData V4.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/odatateam/archive/2014/12/08/function-amp-action-in-web-api-v2-2-for-odata-v4-0-type-scenario.aspx) for details.

Comment: Since i am using angular's $resource so i have ApiController on the server side but I suppose functions are only possible if i use ODataController. ?

Comment: I thought you were using an ODataController all along. I'm surprised that `EnableQuery` worked with an ApiController. You can write the equivalent of an OData function on ApiController with a route like "CommandsRest/StoreCommandSubgraph".